# PHP/MYSQL compare/contrast values of an array (soccer tournament schedule)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, schedule, tournament

I'm trying to create a soccer tournament schedule.
The problem with this is, that I don't know how to compare or contrast the values ​​in an array.
Within an array, every value should be compared to every other value except its own.
For example, there are these teams: Team1, Team2, Team3, Team4.

Now the Code should generate the following:

```
Team1 - Team2 
Team3 - Team4 
Team2 - Team3 
Team1 - Team4 
Team2 - Team4 
Team1 - Team3
```

It is important, that each team plays against all other teams, but if possible not one after the other. I don't need something like this:

```
Team1 - Team2 
Team1 - Team3 
Team1 - Team4 
...and so on
```

Further, it should also work with an odd number of teams.

Another easy example:

Array:

```
$teams('Team1', 'Team2', 'Team3', 'Team4');
```

Output:

```
|Team A | Against | Team B |
|:----- |:------: |-------:|
|Team1  |    -    |Team2   |
|Team3  |    -    |Team4   |
|Team2  |    -    |Team3   |
|Team1  |    -    |Team4   |
... an so on
```

I would be glad about an answer, thanks.

Comment: One way would be to generate all pairs of teams and then randomize the result.

Comment: But even if the results are random, it is possible for a team to play twice in a row, isn't it?

Comment: Oh, I thought you meant teams shouldn't *necessarily* play twice in a row. If you want to ensure that, it'll take a bit more. I'll try to dig a bit more. I think there's a mathematical name for that sort of sequence.

Comment: In your example, you have "Team 3 and Team 4" play followed by "Team 2 and Team 3" play-- doesn't that mean Team 3 plays twice in a row?

Answer (score 0):

This should be a good starting point...

```php
<?php

$teams = ['Team 1', 'Team 2', 'Team 3', 'Team 4'];
$games = [];

for ($index = 0, $indexMax = count($teams); $index < $indexMax; $index++) {
    foreach ($teams as $indexT => $team) {
        if ($indexT === $index) {
            continue;
        }
        $games[] = [$teams[$index] => $team];
    }
}

shuffle($games);
```

Comment: `shuffle()` does not ensure: `but if possible not one after the other`